# Рефакторинг кода, как сделать красиво?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Начал писать Бота для Telegram, который будет помогать в айтишных делах.
Основная идея в том, чтобы завести каждый компьютер в базу и плюс привязка по пользователю, который в текущее время сидит за компьютером.
Хочу запустить на сервере, чтобы бы в бесконечном цикле собирало инфу и оповещало об изменениях.

Написал класс для сбора данных с компьютера по `wmi`. Вот пример

```
import wmi
import config

class Computer:

    def hdd_info(ip):
        hdd = []
        wql  = 'SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive'
        try:
            c = wmi.WMI(ip, user=config.admin, password=config.password)
            for computer in c.query(wql):
                hdd.append(computer.Model)
                hdd.append(computer.SerialNumber)
                hdd.append(computer.Size)
            return hdd
        except:
            return hdd


    def motherboard_info(ip):
        motherboard = []
        wql  = 'SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard'
        try:
            c = wmi.WMI(ip, user=config.admin, password=config.password)
            for computer in c.query(wql):
                motherboard = [computer.Manufacturer, computer.Product]
            return motherboard
        except:
            return motherboard
```

Теперь начинаю работу со всем этим. Вот функция `Main`:

```
ip_subnet = ["192.168.4.", "192.168.5."]

def main():
    i = 55
    for ip in range(len(ip_subnet)):
        while i <= 255:
            ip_adr = ip_subnet[ip] + str(i)
            response = subprocess.call(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip_adr])
            if(response == 0):
                try:
                    wql = 'SELECT *  FROM Win32_computerSystem'
                    c = wmi.WMI(ip_adr, user=config.admin, password=config.password)
                    for computer in c.query(wql):
                        check_in_db_if_ping(computer.DNSHostName, ip_adr, computer.UserName)
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                 check_in_db_if_not_ping(ip_adr)
            i += 1
        i = 0
```

Тут я циклом перебираю все наши подсети и с помощью запроса получаю первичные данные. Если данные получены, передаю их в следующую функцию, которая проверяет есть ли такой компьютер в базе `check_in_db_if_ping`. Данная функция очень длинная и я приведу ее не всю.

```
def check_in_db_if_ping(hostname, ip, user=None):
    cursor.execute('SELECT IP FROM Computers WHERE IP  = ?', (ip,))
    check_ip = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute('SELECT HostName FROM Computers WHERE HostName  = ?', (hostname,))
    check_hostname = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    if len(check_ip) == 0 and len(check_hostname) == 0:
        add_to_db(hostname, ip, user)
```

`user = None`  стоит потому-что компьютер может быть включен, а текущий пользователь отошел и тогда при запросе, придет None, там вроде есть какой-то таймаут, если пользователь не активен какое-то время.

В фунцкии `check_in_db_if_ping` я проверяю, есть ли такой IP адрес и `HostName` в базе не существует, то я начинаю заводить его в базу и передаю в функцию `add_to_db`

И вот самое **главное**, как выглядит функция добавления компьютера в базу:

```
def add_to_db(hostname, ip, user = None):
    motherboard = Computer.motherboard_info(ip)
    ram = Computer.ram_info(ip)
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Computers (HostName, IP, Status, OnTime, OffTime, MotherBoard, RAM) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                  (hostname, ip, "Online", str(time),"-",motherboard[0] + " " + motherboard[1], str(ram[0])))
    last_id = cursor.lastrowid
    conn.commit()
    if user != None:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO User (ComputerId, Login) VALUES (?,?)', (last_id, user))
        conn.commit()
```

Мне в эта функция не нравится: этот длинный запрос и склейка данных, но как упростить я его я не знаю.

Можно как-нибудь собрать, грубо говоря, все данные о компьютере в лист и просто листом все записать в базу? И вообще есть ли замечания по коду?

Comment: как вариант: использовать ORM, из новых https://ponyorm.com/ из старых sqlalchemy

Comment: Вообще ORM это единственный вариант, но тогда желательно вам будет переписать все запросы к базе и сделать через ORM.
А вообще я бы посоветовал использовать проверку не `if len(n) == 0`, а `if not n` ну и не `if user != None` , a `if a is not None` . еще почитайте об используйте `def __init__(self)` и использовать все прелести ООП (Что бы эти 3 буквы не означали). И вообще легче было бы сказать что можно поменять если вы предоставили весь код, допустим на `GitHub`. Можно заменить `while` на `for i in range(25,255)`. Еще не стоит делать просто `except` это плохой вариант (ОЧЕНЬ!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую обратить ваше внимание к двум книгам, которые считаю достаточно важными для выработки навыков написания чистого кода:

1) "Clean code" Роберта Мартина https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5011068/

2) "Рефакторинг" Фаулера
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1308678/

В них вы найдете ответы на ваши вопросы о том, как декомпозировать функцию, что можно вынести в отдельный класс, почему метод на 100 строк плохой и как с этим бороться.

Не проигнорируйте рекоммендацию, а действительно скачайте(купите) книгу и у вас появится понимание о том, как рефакторить.

Answer (score 0):

> Можно как-нибудь собрать, грубо говоря, все данные о компьютере в лист
>   и просто листом все записать в базу? И вообще есть ли замечания по
>   коду?

Можно попробовать типа байт машины(но это очень мудренно-сам давно пробую).Пусть push_str <строка например имя компютера>(push_str на самом деле число) и есть основная команда типа this_is_comp (тоже число), интерпретатор считывает ленту, видит this_is_com, берет со стека строку - может формировать sql запрос, потом пакетом все выполняет,как-то так)